# how to enable opcache.load_comments php 7.1

Tags: php, ubuntu, opcache

I have server ubuntu 14.04.1
PHP Version 7.1.11-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.1.11-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

in php.ini file, I have

```
opcache.save_comments=1
```

I add

```
opcache.load_comments=1
```

in `phpinfo()` i get

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename  no value    no value
opcache.consistency_checks  0   0
opcache.dups_fix    Off Off
opcache.enable  On  On
opcache.enable_cli  Off Off
opcache.enable_file_override    Off Off
opcache.error_log   no value    no value
opcache.fast_shutdown   0   0
opcache.file_cache  no value    no value
opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks   1   1
opcache.file_cache_only 0   0
opcache.file_update_protection  2   2
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180 180
opcache.huge_code_pages Off Off
opcache.inherited_hack  On  On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 8   8
opcache.lockfile_path   /tmp    /tmp
opcache.log_verbosity_level 1   1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   10000   10000
opcache.max_file_size   0   0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   5   5
opcache.memory_consumption  128 128
opcache.opt_debug_level 0   0
opcache.optimization_level  0x7FFFBFFF  0x7FFFBFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model  no value    no value
opcache.protect_memory  0   0
opcache.restrict_api    no value    no value
opcache.revalidate_freq 2   2
opcache.revalidate_path Off Off
opcache.save_comments   1   1
opcache.use_cwd On  On
opcache.validate_permission Off Off
opcache.validate_root   Off Off
opcache.validate_timestamps On  On

var_dump(ini_get('opcache.load_comments'));
```

give my

```
bool(false);
```

even

```
ini_set('opcache.load_comments', 1);    
var_dump(ini_get('opcache.load_comments'));
```

give my false.

Comment: Did you restart the server (apache)?

Comment: Yes i restart apache

Answer (score 1):

The `opcache.load_comments` configuration directive was removed in PHP 7.0.0, as mentioned on the [opcache Runtime Configuration](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php) page.